# reactjs and fixed-data-table-2: 100% width for table

Tags: reactjs, fixed-data-table

I am learning [fixed-data-table-2](https://schrodinger.github.io/fixed-data-table-2/) and trying to pass a width of `100%` to it.

```
<Table
rowsCount={this.state.countries.length}
rowHeight={50}
headerHeight={50}
width={'100%'}
height={500}>
```

This works (in Chrome at least), and the table indeed stretches to full page width, but the console is predictably flooded with errors:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `width` of type `string` supplied to `FixedDataTable`, expected `number`.
```

I understand that

> FixedDataTable does not provide a layout reflow mechanism or calculate content layout information such as width and height of the cell contents.

so what is a proper way of stretching it to full container width?

Answer (score 0):

For a start you could wrap `<Table />` component in a div with a `width: 100%`. 
Then attach a ref to this div and read its **clientWidth**. Once you have that, simply pass it as width to `<Table />` component.

This of course gets more complicated if you want to consider user changing the browser width - you need a way to listen to either window or element size change - and change the width accordingly.